# Bridged routers and firewall

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall

I have started to do quite a bit of research on securing my home security after a virus outbreak between some computers. Wanting to isolate two sets of computers, I came to the conclusion to make a sub-network and firewall them off.

After a bit of talking with my friends they said to me that 99% of the routers don't activate the firewall in bridge mode and it has to be connected to the phone line for the firewall to actually work. Is that actually true and I have to look for a special type of router for what I'm doing, or does every router have that?

TL;DR: Do all routers activate the firewall when in bridge mode?

Comment: are you really on phone line for your wan, or do you perhaps mean cat5 cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific answer to your query. some do, some don't. personally I've had more problems disabling the firewall on my bridges. From what you describe though, you are not bridging but routing. bridging connects two segments of the same IP network (a single subnet) so if you have two subnets, the router connecting them needs to be in routing mode.

That said, firewalling will help you with interactive intruders, spies, and worms, but don't do much of anything for viruses or trojans  (unless specifically configured for each and every specific virus/trojans communication signature, in which case you are probably using an IDPS).

to fight viruses, keep your applications up to date. viruses exploit vulnerabilities in application software (worms exploit system software). Keep your antivirus up to date, and enable any heuristic or behavioural analysis features.

for Trojans, the most effective protection is to avoid shady locations on line, implement adblocking, and look into javascript whitelisting like NoScript on your browser. don't download anything free except from the people who made it. scan all downloads (but remember, most of the time, with a drive-by-download attack, you won't know that your browser has just opened an invisible pdf in the background, which has then broken its sandbox, and executed js code to download and install a raskit)